# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : search bar for searching by name and ingredient

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I'm building a cocktail bar app using ASP.NET Core 5 MVC and Entity Framework. I'm implementing the search bar functionality right now. I made it work that when I enter the name of a cocktail, it says the cocktail(s) with the search input in it. For example, typing "Cuba" will show the cocktail "Cuba Libre", and typing "Martini" will show "Martini and "Lemon Drop Martini".

On top of this I want that when I search for an ingredient from the database, to show all the cocktails that have said ingredient. If I search for "Rum" then I should see "Cuba Libre", "Mojito", etc.

In my `CocktailsController`, I have this method responsible for the search bar:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Filter(string searchString)
{
        var allCocktails = await _service.GetAllAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            var filteredResult = allCocktails.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(searchString));
            //  var filteredResult = allCocktails.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(searchString || n.Ingredients_Cocktails.Contains(searchString)).ToList());
            return View("Index", filteredResult);
        }

        return View("Index", allCocktails);
}
```

These are the models for Cocktail, Ingredient and Ingredients_Cocktails (this is basically the recipe of the cocktail)

```
public class Cocktail:IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DrinkCategory DrinkCategory { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public List<Ingredient_Cocktail> Ingredients_Cocktails { get; set; }

    // Glass
    public int GlassId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GlassId")]
    public Glass Glass {get; set; }

}

public class Ingredient:IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="An image is required")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Brand")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A brand is required")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public List<Ingredient_Cocktail> Ingredients_Cocktails { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient_Cocktail
{
    public int CocktailId { get; set; }
    public Cocktail Cocktail { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

My attempts have been somewhere along this version, but this still doesn't work for searching by ingredients:

```cs
var filteredResult = allCocktails.Where(cocktail =>
            cocktail.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
            cocktail.Ingredients_Cocktails.Any(ingredientCocktail =>
                ingredientCocktail.Ingredient.Name.Contains(searchString)))
            .ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please share how is  "Rum"  is related to "Cuba Libre" could you please share a sample allCocktails details along with sample data.

Comment: "Rum" is an ingredient of the "Cuba Libre" cocktail. I don't understand what do you mean by the second part of your comment.

Comment: What I meant is, would be great if there any demo sample data that would be great in order to visualize about your expected output.

Comment: Let's say we have the following cocktails with the ingredients mentioned: Cuba Libre(rum, lime juice, cola); Gimlet(gin, lime juice); Kamikaze(vodka, lime juice, triplesec); Martini(gin, vermouth).

When I search for "Cuba" or Cuba Libre" I should only get the Cuba Libre cocktail.
But when I search for "lime juice" I should get Cuba Libre, Gimlet and Kamikaze, as lime juice is an ingredient in all these cocktails.
My code above only works for cocktails' names, and I would like make it work for ingredients as well.